# How to open the Blackberry email app, ready to compose an email to a given address?

Tags: blackberry, email

In my Blackberry application, I have a email address I want the user to be able to send an email to. I would like to have the built in Email Application run the compose screen with the "to" field filled in with the email address I supply, similar to how desktop mail clients respond to a "mailto" link. Does the API have a function for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Invoke Class](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/invoke/Invoke.html)

With a [MessageArgument](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/invoke/MessageArguments.html)

And you should be ok

If you need more customization Use the `Message` class with the `Adress` class to add to the Message en then send it to the `MessageArgument` then you can send it to `Invoke`

You can also see a more detailed explanation on [RIM website](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/deliverables/608/BlackBerry_Application_Developer_Guide_Volume_2.pdf)