# Open compose email window directly in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to open the Blackberry email app, ready to compose an email to a given address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762034/how-to-open-the-blackberry-email-app-ready-to-compose-an-email-to-a-given-addre)

I am clicking on a button. On button click, user should move to "Compose email" screen.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762034/how-to-open-the-blackberry-email-app-ready-to-compose-an-email-to-a-given-addre

Comment: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/608/BlackBerry_Application_Developer_Guide_Volume_2.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    MessageArguments ma = new MessageArguments(MessageArguments.ARG_NEW, <recipients>, <subject>, <body>);
    //Alternatively, if you don't want to provide default values: ma = new MessageArguments(MessageArguments.ARG_NEW);

    Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_MESSAGES, ma);
```

Answer (score 1):

this is working fine , try this,

```
public void SendMail() 
        {


            String htmlContent =  "Body part";

            Message msg = new Message(); 
            try 
            { 
                final Address address = new Address("",""); 
                Address[] addresses = {address}; 
                msg.addRecipients(net.rim.blackberry.api.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO, addresses); 
                msg.setContent(htmlContent); 
                msg.setSubject("Subject"); 

                Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_MESSAGES, new MessageArguments(msg));

            } 
            catch (AddressException e) 
            { 
                e.printStackTrace(); 
                System.out.println("AddressException -->"+e.getMessage()); 
            } 
            catch (MessagingException e) 
            { 
                e.printStackTrace(); 
                System.out.println("MessagingException -->"+e.getMessage()); 
            }
        }
```